# Programatically set v$session program property

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss

I found some answers on the problem but none that i could make work in my case. My problem is that I load a datasource from my JBoss configuration with spring:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/oracleDatasource" pool-name="jdbc/oracleDatasource" enabled="true">
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                    jdbc:oracle:thin:@URL:1522:SID
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="connectionProperties">
                    v$session.program=MyAPP
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>oracle-jdbc</driver>
```

The spring loading is made as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/jdbc/oracleDatasource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

As you can see, I have set the `v$session.program` property in JBoss, it works well.

The problem is that i have several applications (war) that can be deployed on the same JBoss server, using this configuration. What I want to do in this case is to have each of my application to have its own name written in the `v$session.program` property.

So basically, i would like to be able to load the same datasource on each app but to have each of them using its own name to log the program property in oracle DB. Is it possible or do I have to have one datasource for each application hosted?

Comment: Would putting information into `v$session.module` or `v$session.client_info` be an alternative?

Comment: Yes it would be a viable alternative (the field client_info is not used) but i'm facing the same issue with this one, i don't know how to set this property after the datasource has been loaded. As the connection is automatically created with the jdbcTemplate call, i cant modify its properties on connection creation as it is explained in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876956/setting-client-info-in-jdbc-for-oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need it to **intercept** each call of *getConnection* from connection pool.

You must obtain a real Oracle connection - not a proxy - and call the **setClientInfo** on 12c or **setEndToEndMetrics** in older versions to set the action / client / module identification.

An example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571537/how-to-set-the-client-identifier-in-oracle-using-spring-mybatis/32574531#32574531).

Also note that the use of *dbms_application_info* for this same purpose works as well, but this **produces a one server roundtrip too much**. The *setClientInfo* doesn't produce server call, but stores this information **for the next statement execution** (which is the preformance saving approach).

Also note that to use this feature, your driver must match perfectly with your database - the strange exeptions you can see while setting teh client info are in most cases caused by the incompatibility of teh JDBC driver and the RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tried to get the real connection but got stuck in a case because of the framework creating its own conneciton. I used the dmbs_application_info, it does the trick for me right now. I set an activation mode for this information so that i don't have the extra call for each connection but just on specific times, its enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: @user3218683, you are correct; each framework wraps up the connection in an own proxy object. You may check the  javadoc for a method like *getConnection* that returns the original DB connection. And of course the DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO works fine, but - as said - cost one round-trip more. *Feel free to up-vote or accept the answer that you found useful:)*

Answer (score 0):

If putting this information into `v$session.module` or `v$session.client_info` is an option, you can do using Java code.

All you need to do is call [`dbms_application_info.set_module()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#i996826) or [`dbms_application_info.set_client_info()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#CHEJCFGG) after your Java code obtained the connection from the datasource.

Something like this:

```
Connection conn = ... // get connection from the DataSource
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call dbms_application_info.set_client_info(?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, "Some interesting information");
cstmt.execute();
```

Comment: This is the PL/SQL approach, to be used only in case that the JDBC solution fails to work for a specific JDBC driver and RDBMS version