# Specify v$session.program for R2DBC Oracle connection

Tags: oracle, r2dbc

I was trying to set the v$session.program at the connection from a R2DBC Oracle connection (within a Spring application)

For now I've tried this but without success.
ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactoryOptions.parse(dbUrl).mutate().option(Option.valueOf("v$session.program"), "PROGRAMNAME").build());

Would this be possible to set in any way?

Thanks for help.

Comment: There is similar one here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027389/programatically-set-vsession-program-property

Comment: thanks @Pankaj. I've seen this but it isn't clear how in R2DBC I could intercept the connection creation to make such settings.
So this question is really an extension of that one with focus on how to do it with R2DBC Oracle drivers

Answer (score 0):

Oracle R2DBC 0.4.0 does not support the v$session properties as ConnectionFactoryOptions. However, I think it should, so I'll be adding support for that in the next release of Oracle R2DBC.

If anyone needs a temporary workaround, these properties can be set as JVM system properties. System properties will bypass Oracle R2DBC's connection property filter.